# Python docx content unreadable in terminal

Tags: python, encode, docx

I want to print out contents of a docx file to my terminal using python. However when I use print(contents) I get a unreadable string:

```
PK♥♦¶!gs(/�☺(   ☻[Content_Types].xml �♦☻(�☻Ė�j�0►E����Ѷ�JR(
```

I know this is because my terminal cannot read a docxs file, but how do print the contents that is human readable? Do I have to encode or decode somehow?

Comment: .docx files are zipped XML I think, so you would have to unzip before trying to print.

Comment: you can uses the docx library to read it https://pypi.org/project/python-docx/

Comment: I dont actually have the docx document. I am retrieving the contents of an object on a server,  ie the server has the document and I just receive the content---so in this case it is a docx file but in other cases it could be a pdf of excel. I want to be able to later use regex on the content, but I can do that since the output is not readable